# outer jquery draggable/resizable div's not allowing me to select text of inner span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamically created jquery draggable div, that has a nested jquery resizable div within it.

Inside the resizable div I have a nested span with some text inside.

I can drag the div about and resize it.

I want to be able to select the text within the span but the parent divs are blocking me from doing it.

I can click on the text and call an alert but still cannot highlight the text.

Am I missing something obvious?

I have created a jsfiddle so you can see it in action.

you can resize and drag the box around and if you click on the text you get an alert, but cannot select the text

http://jsfiddle.net/ARc7G/28/

any help greatly appreciated as I am tearing my hair out

heres the code
     javascript

```
  function createtextbox(i, id, top, left, width, height, content,zindex,borderwidth,borderstyle,bordercolor,padding) {
id = id + i;
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
newdiv.setAttribute('class', 'dragbox');
newdiv.setAttribute('iterate', i);
newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
newdiv.style.top = top + "px";
newdiv.style.left = left + "px";
newdiv.style.borderWidth = "1px";
newdiv.style.cursor = 'move';
newdiv.style.zIndex = zindex;
newdiv.innerHTML = "</div><br><div id='div" + i + "' name='textarea[" + i + "]'  class='textarea1' style='padding:"+padding+"px; border-width:"+borderwidth+"px; border-style:"+borderstyle+";  border-color:"+bordercolor+"; width:"+width+"px; height:"+height+"px;position:absolute; top:10px;left:0px;overflow-y: none;background-color:transparent;'><span id='span" + i + "'>" + content + "</span></div>";
var htmlData = $('#' + i).html();
newdiv.innerHTML = newdiv.innerHTML + "<br><input name='contents[" + i + "]' type='hidden' value='" + content + "'/>";
newdiv.innerHTML = newdiv.innerHTML + "<br><input type='hidden' value='" + i + "' name='id[" + i + "]'><br><input name='box_type[" + i + "]' type='hidden' value='text'/>";
newdiv.innerHTML = newdiv.innerHTML + "<br><input type='hidden' value='" + width + "' name='width[" + i + "]' id='width" + i + "'><br><input type='hidden' value='" + height + "' name='height[" + i + "]' id='height" + i + "'>";
newdiv.innerHTML = newdiv.innerHTML + "<br><input type='hidden' value='" + left + "' name='left[" + i + "]' id='left" + i + "'><br><input type='hidden' value='" + top + "' name='top[" + i + "]' id='top" + i + "'>";
document.getElementById("frmMain").appendChild(newdiv);

var top_button_left_pos = -75;
var spanclick = document.getElementById('span' + i);
spanclick.onclick = function (e) {       
    alert("hello world");
};


$(function () {
    $("#div" + i).resizable({
        autoHide: true
    });
    $("#div" + i).resizable({           
    });

    $("#" + id).draggable({           
    });
});
}


createtextbox('1', 'draggable', '15', '15', '300', '300', 'newtextarea','1','1','solid','#000000','3');
```

html

```
 <form id="frmMain" name="frmMain" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div id="content"></div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Seems like the click event is already too late to prevent the drag (since it's on mouse up and I suspect draggable is using down). Will give it a try in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok don't prevent the default (that is what you need to select after all) and handle mouse down instead of click (I was right, the click fires too late):

```
spanclick.onmousedown = function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
};
```

Also reset the cursor style it inherits from the draggable div and you are good to go.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ARc7G/31/

Comment: Damyan, I have updated the jsfiddle as I am trying to wrap the selected text in bold tags. http://jsfiddle.net/ARc7G/32/ can you see where I am going wrong, thanks

Comment: Aye, it's a span (not an actual textarea tag) therefore the value is not it's visible text. Use .html() instead as in http://jsfiddle.net/ARc7G/36/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at

http://jsfiddle.net/ARc7G/29/

At the final, I added

```
$("#span"+i).css('color','red');
```

Comment: you still cannot highlight the text with the mouse. What I need is to be able to select the text